Projective model of complex manifold
Let $\mathbb C^4$ be the complex vector space equipped with the symmetric bilinear form  of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(z,w) =  z_1w_1 + z_2 w_2- z_3 w_3- z_4 w_4.$$ The set $$X_{\mathbb C} = \{z \in \mathbb C^4 \mid b(z,z) = -1\}$$ is a complex manifold.
Can we write the  projective model of $X_{\mathbb C}$ ?
The  projective model of $X_{\mathbb C}$ is $$X_{\mathbb C}= \{[z]\in \mathbb{CP}^3 \mid \langle z, z\rangle_{2,2} <0\}$$ Does it make any sence?

Side note: Any nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb C^n$ is equivalent to the standard one $\sum z_j^2$ up to base change, so bilinear forms on complex vector spaces don't have signatures like real forms. You could talk about the signature of a Hermitian form on $\mathbb C^n$.

When you want to build the projective model of an affine hypersurface, you just need to "homogenize" your equation by adding a variable (let say $z_0$).
In this situation, you have $$X_\mathbb{C}= \left\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}^4 | z_1^2+z_2^2-z_3^2-z_4^2 +1 = 0\right \rbrace,$$
hence you get $$ \overline{X} = \left\lbrace z \in \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^4 | z_0^2 + z_1^2+z_2^2-z_3^2-z_4^2 = 0\right \rbrace.$$
In fact, your guess is not even projective since it is not compact.
